# Converting a sequence of numbers (not in any data structure) into an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a sequence of numbers that I somehow obtain from an external source, not separated by any commas and not in a data structure, e.g: 1 1.5 120202.4343 58 -2442.5

Where distinct numbers are separated by a space(s).

Is there a way for me to write a program to quickly convert this sequence into a list or numpy array [1, 1.5, 120202.4343, 58 ,-2442.5].

Comment: how do you import the numbers?

Comment: They have to already be in a string or something. You can't just have some numbers separated by spaces not in something. They're probably already in a string. You can just split the string if that's the case.

Comment: "and not in a data structure" that doesn't make any sense. The source must be *some* data structure, event if it is `bytes` or something like that. Please be specific about *exactly* what you are dealing with

Comment: Have you solved this issue? ( @Carcigenicate comment is a very good way to go) if so, you should share the solution as an answer below. This way other beginners coming through here with the same problem might benefit as well.

Comment: I copied this data and pasted it into my interpreter. So it is not in any data structure (as far as my limited understanding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "not in a data structure", that doesn't make much sense. But assuming you have a string, then `numpy` even provides a utility method for this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = '1 1.5 120202.4343 58 -2442.5'
>>> np.fromstring(data, sep=' ')
array([ 1.00000000e+00,  1.50000000e+00,  1.20202434e+05,  5.80000000e+01,
       -2.44250000e+03])
```

Comment: Very nice, it also performs at roughly the same speed as list comprehension (from my tests!). +1 for that.

Comment: I mean I copied and pasted the data from another page into my python interpreter. So it is awaiting to be executed as it is.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> in_str = '1 1.5 120202.4343 58 -2442.5'
>>> list(map(float, in_str.split(' ')))
[1, 1.5, 120202.4343, 58, -2442.5]
```

Comment: Use float instead of int!

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers say using split() can be used for this problem once you get the data as a string.  I feel like it is valuable to show that

```
with open(filename,'r') as fil:
  f = fil.read().split()
```

will let you put your external source file in a variable *filename* and then split that data into a list saved as f.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe nobody came up with the obvious:

```
np.array(your_string.split(),dtype=float)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` and split the spaces to get a list of strings. Then simply convert each string to a float using type casting. This is achieved in one line using list comprehension.

For example:

```
x = '1 1.5 120202.4343 58 -2442.5'
output = [float(i) for i in x.split(" ")]
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 1.5, 120202.4343, 58 ,-2442.5]
```

---

If you input numbers come in one after another, then you can simply append to an existing list:

```
output = []

# Loop until an escape string is provided and get append input number to list
while True:
  x = input() # Next input number
  if x == 'escape_string_of_your_choice':
     break
  else:
    output.append(x)
```

Likewise, if your sequence length is known in advance, you can initialize the list to a certain length and use indexing to assign the next input number in the sequence (you need a counter to keep track of where you are):

```
counter = 0 # First index has value 0
output = [0]*N # N is the length of the sequence

# Now looping is better defined (no need to provide escape strings)
while counter < N:
  x = input() # Next input number
  output[counter] = x
  counter += 1 # Increment after element added to list
```

---

Lastly, comparing list comprehension to astype array forming in numpy provided in some answers we see that list comprehension is vastly superior in terms of execution speed.

```
import timeit

code_to_test = '''
import numpy as np
number_string = "1 1.5 120202.4343 58 -2442.5"
number_list = number_string.split(" ")
numbers_array = np.array(number_list).astype(np.float)'''

code_comp = '''
import numpy as np # Not needed but just to compare fairly
x = '1 1.5 120202.4343 58 -2442.5'
output = [float(i) for i in x.split(" ")]'''

test_time = timeit.timeit(code_to_test, number=10000)
compt_time = timeit.timeit(code_comp, number=10000)

print(test_time) # 0.6834872080944479
print(compt_time) # 0.028420873917639256
print(test_time/compt_time) # 24.048775209204436
```

Obviously these numbers will change each run but you can see that most of the time comprehension will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You can load the numbers as a single string, then `split` the string by spaces. This will give you a list of strings:

```py
number_string = "1 1.5 120202.4343 58 -2442.5"
number_list = number_string.split(" ")
```

Then, you can easily convert that list of strings into a numpy array of floats using `astype`:

```py
numbers_array = np.array(number_list).astype(np.float)
```

Comment: Nice! Wouldn't list comprehension work faster to convert the split list into floats?

Comment: @lbragile probably not.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillage List comprehension method described above performs **around 15 times faster** after 1000 trials than using astype(). See my answer for my test script.

Comment: If you’re going with NumPy, couldn’t you just use `fromstring()`?